# The order of the Quaternion Group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I'm trying to find an easy way to prove the order of the Quaternion Group is a non-abelian group of order 8 without many computations, anyone has an idea?

Note we can define the Quaternion Group as the group generated by the following matrices $$A=
        \left( \begin{matrix}
         0 & 1 \\
        -1 &  0\\
        \end{matrix}
\right)$$ $$B=
        \left( \begin{matrix}
         0 & i \\
        i &  0\\
        \end{matrix}
\right)$$
Thanks

Comment: First you have to tell us what definition of the quaternion group you are working with. After all, it can be defined to be the nonabelian, nondihedral group of order 8.

Comment: @GerryMyerson ok thank you for the remarks

Comment: @GerryMyerson I think that's good now

Comment: Now that you have defined the group, you can show the matrices satisfy the relations in @Babak's answer, then you just have to show that those three relations imply the group elements are as Babak gives them.

Comment: @GerryMyerson thanks this makes the problem much easier.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Or maybe you can find the following an interesting point, a very similar to Ittay's simple way: $$Q_8=\langle a,b\mid a^4=1, a^2=b^2, ba=a^{-1}b\rangle=\{1,a,b,a^2,ab,a^3,a^2b,a^3b\}$$ Note that $ba=a^{-1}b$  shows it is non abelian.

Comment: I think $(ab)^2=1$ is wrong. You can use $ba=a^{-1}b$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson: Thanks. I had checked it by GAP before posting. I fixed it accordingly.

Comment: thank you very much, that helped me a lot

Comment: I didn't understand why this $ba=a^{-1}b$ implies that this group is non abelian. Thanks again.

Comment: If the group were abelian, you'd also have $ba=ab$ --- that's what abelian means, right? If you have both $ba=ab$ and $ba=a^{-1}b$, then you have $a=a^{-1}$, right? so you also have $a^2=1$, right? but we don't have $a^2=1$, we only have $a^4=1$, so if we have $ba=a^{-1}b$ then we can't have $ba=ab$, and the group can't be abelian.

Comment: Nice job! You know your groups ;-) $+1$

Answer (score 3):

Depending on the definition you have in mind, the following might work for you: $ij=k$ while $ji=-k$ shows that it is not abelian. Counting the number of elements in $\{\pm 1, \pm i, \pm j, \pm k\}$ shows that it is a group of order $8$.