# Prove the group defined by the following relations has eight elements and is not isomorphic to $\Delta_4$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-presentation, combinatorial-group-theory, cayley-table

I'm working out the exercises in MacLane and Birkhoff's *Algebra*. The exercise in question is the II.5.8:

[image]

where $\Delta_4$ stands for the fourth dihedral group.

Now I'm stuck trying to answer the first part because my reasoning leads to further equalities that nowhere help me build a Cayley table. I'm actually lost with the procedure itself. For now what I've be trying is to assume there are the elements $1,a,a^2,a^3$, but I can't find the remaining elements.

From the fact that $a^4 = 1$ I conclude $a^{-1} = a^3$, which in turn implies that
$$b^{-1} a b = a^3$$

In the other hand, $a^2 = b^2$ leads to multiple new relations, which will further affect the consequences of $b^{-1}ab = a^{-1}$, for example concluding that $ba = aba^2$, which doesn't help.

This is, the defining relations are not helping me find which elements belong to the group (is $b^{-1}$ really in the group, or something like $ba^2$ takes its place?). In the case of $\Delta_3$ I was able to build its Cayley table from its defining relations because I knew beforehand which elements where in, but it is not the case here. I would really appreciate a complete explanation on how we build the Cayley table of a group, given a set of defining relations, but not the elements of the set.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You seem very confused. Od course $b^{-1}$ is in the group. All strings formed from the symbols $a$, $a^{-1}$, $b$, $b^{-1}$ represent elements of the group, but the same element is represented by more than one (in fact infinitely many) strings. It turns out that the eight elements $a^ib^j$ with $0 \le i < 4$ and $0 \le j < 2$ represent distinct elements of the group, and that every element of the group is equal to exactly one of these eight elements.

Comment: I would suggest reading a more modern exposition of algebra.

Comment: @Pedro Tamaroff, which one? I want a very comprehensive one, and for now I'm happy with this one, but I'm open to any suggestion.

Comment: @Hal For group theory, you can look at Rotman's Introduction to Group Theory. For general algebra, you can look at Dummit and Foote, at Lang, the older Jacobson, among others. You can do some research and find out which one fits you. The book you're reading is *really* outdated. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me try to frame the problem in another way. Start with all elements formed from the symbols in $\{a, a^{-1}, b, b^{-1}\}$, like $a^{10}$ or $b^3a^{-1}b^{-2}$. Now, with the relations given, you will notice that most of these are actually "the same" as each other (e.g. $a^3 = a^{-1}$, as you've pointed out).

As Derek Holt commented, what you want to do at this point is show that none of the elements of the form $a^ib^j$ with $i = 0, 1, 2, 3$ and $j = 0, 1$ are "the same" as each other (so you know you have at least 8 different elements in your group), and that every string made from the symbols in $\{a, a^{-1}, b, b^{-1}\}$ is "the same" as one of them (so you know you have exactly 8 elements in your group).

From this it will be easy to build your Cayley table.

Comment: I am wondering how the student using this book  is intended to show that the eight elements are distinct. The usual way of doing this is to find some concrete representation of the group, such as the group of $2 \times 2$ complex matrices described [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/360122/), but to do that you need to know something about the group already. It can can also be exhibited as a subgroup of the multiplicative group of quaternions.

Comment: Yes I did mean that. The question says "show that this presentation defines a group of order 8" which suggests that they are supposed to prove that. I was just wondering how, but I would need to look at the book to see what techniques are available. (I do have a copy, but it is in my office at the UofWarwick, and we still do not have easy access!)

Comment: @Derek Whoops, for some reason I only read part (b)! I've deleted my comment to save me some embarrassment. To prove that it has order eight, it would be sufficient to prove that it has centre of order two and also maps onto a group of order four, which seems not too hard (and is also true).

Comment: Well, let me say the notion of *center* has not been exposed so far in the book. Following Pedro Tamaroff's advice I started reading Foote and Dummit's *Abstract Algebra* but, sincerely, I was enjoying so much MacLane and Birkhoff's book that I don't want to let it down so easily. I wonder if it's normal to be unable to answer a question in a first reading, and if it's reasonable to keep reading even though I abandoned some questions. It's my first time studying general algebra, and I'm a bit embarrassed to say that, even with your help, I cannot solve the exercise.